# How this keyword works in functions nested in member functions?

Tags: javascript, this

Hello I am learning JavaScript and I was trying to understand how the the 'this' keyword.

Say I have the following JavsScript Code:

```
var a = function(){
    console.log('this value for function a:');
    console.log(this);
}


var obj = {
    name: 'Object1',
    objFunc: function(){
        console.log('this value for function objFunc in Object1:');
        console.log(this);

        var nestedFunc = function(){
            console.log('this value for nested function nestedFunc in Object1:');
            console.log(this);
        }

        nestedFunc();
    }
}

a();
obj.objFunc();
```

This results in the following:

- this value for function a: 'Window' object (the global object)
- this value for function objFunc in Object1: The object 'Object1'
- this value for nested function nestedFunc in Object1: 'Window' object (the global object)

Results 1,2 make sense to me.

- on examining Window object, a() is a function created as a method on the window global object so here 'this' points to it.
- on examining Object1 object, objFunc() is a function created as a method on the Object1 object so here 'this' points to it.

However I don't understand why the third result of nested func in object 'Object1' points to Window.

In the console if I examine the Window object and check its attributes I see that it has a field for a() so I can see why the 'this' for a() would point to Window. Similarly when I examine the object 'Object1' and check its attributes there is a field for objFunc() so I can see why the 'this' for objFunc() would point to Object1.

My questions are:

1. I do not see a field for nestedFunc() in the Window object so why does 'this' in nestedFunc() point to the Window object?
2. Although there is no separate attribute created in the Object1 object for  nestedFunc(), the nestedFunc() function was created within Object1 so why does 'this' not point to Object1 instead of window?

**Edit:** I think my question has been answered [by this website](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/#When_this_is_most_misunderstood_and_becomes_tricky). From what I understand, closures cannot access the outer function’s 'this' variable by using the this keyword because the 'this' variable is accessible only by the function itself, not by inner functions. So 'this' for the nested function will be undefined hence it will be set to the global object

Comment: I improved the title to distinguish it from the false duplicate and vote for reopen.

Comment: @JanTuroň One of the answers of that other question provided a link to a webpage that answered my question. The website mentions that closures cannot access the outer function’s 'this' variable by using the this keyword because the 'this' variable is accessible only by the function itself, not by inner functions. So 'this' for the nested function will be undefined hence it will be set to the global object.

Comment: Note that that is one difference between arrow functions and regular functions. Arrow functions do not have their own `this` but can access the `this` variable of an outer function.

Comment: Great to read that you found the answer. But actually inner functions **can** access caller's `this` using [Function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) (note the first argument).

Comment: @JanTuroň Inner functions can't access their caller's `this`; they can only access their own `this` value. Using Function.prototype.call just lets you set their `this` value at invocation time. It can be a reference to the same object as the caller's `this` references, but that is still only accessing it's own `this`.